# Sufficient condition in a maximization problem

Tags: calculus

I maximized the function
$$f(x,y)=(x+2)(y+1)$$
subject to
$$4x+6y=130, \quad x,y\geq0$$
and I found $(x,y)=(16,11)$. But the question I'm doing asks me to analyse the "sufficient conditions of second order".

So, I thought I should use some theorem that tells me $(16,11)$ is the max value of $f$. I don't know if I could use Weierstrass' Theorem here and I believe the hessian matrix doesn't help me either.

Comment: Why doesnt checking the hessian work here?

Comment: @MONODA43 I forgot to mention that. Hessian here is $-1$. It's a saddle point, but I don't know how it works about the restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function $f$ as viewed along the curve $4x+6y=130$ only has one degree of freedom (thus only needs one parameter to be expressed). We can write the curve as $y=\frac{130-4x}{6}$ and use this as a substitution in $f$ so that

$$f(x)=(x+2)\bigg(\frac{130-4x}{6}+1\bigg)$$ along the curve (yes, specifically along the curve, this is important). We can then look at the second derivative $f''(x).$ Notice that only the quadratic term of $f(x)$ will contribute to this second derivative so it must be that $$f''(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\bigg[\frac{-4x^2}{6}\bigg] = \frac{-4}{\; 3}<0 \;.$$

This is sufficient to say that $f$ is concave along the curve $4x+6y=130$ and thus an extreme point will achieve a maximum.

The distinction here is that we have just computed a sort of "curvature" of $f$ along $4x+6y=130$ whereas the Hessian matrix gives us an idea about the curvature of $f$ as a whole surface.